# How to trigger a Google Cloud Function when a scheduled compute engine "disk snapshot" is created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-scheduler, event-arc

When a "disk snapshot" is created in Google Cloud - I scheduled the "disk snapshots" with the Google Cloud dashboard - I need to turn it into an "Image", and then export the image to a third party host using `SFTP`.

I have been unable to trigger a Google Cloud Function (it would launch the `gcloud` command to create an "Image" from the "disk snapshot") when a scheduled compute engine "disk snapshot" is created.

In the Google Cloud Logs Explorer I don't see any related event, even if I just search by "snapshot".

I have tried creating an `EventArc` trigger with event type `google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written` and event method `beta.compute.disks.createSnapshot`, but obviously it doesn't work, because there is no such event logged.

I have also tried enabling "Admin Read", "Data Read" and "Data Write" inside "Audit logs" > "Compute Engine API".

Is it even possible to do what I asked?

Or is there a better way to achieve the task?

Comment: can you check if the manual snapshot is working fine by enabling "application consistent snapshot"

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do the exact same thing. I was able to intercept the `v1.compute.snapshots.insert` when manually creating a snapshot, but no luck with Scheduled Snapshots.

Did you maybe get it working?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't manage to get it working.